# Set global xmodmap in Debian

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I currently have `xmodmap` setup for my user so I can type certain special characters. However, this only applies to my user, and I need these characters to be type-able everywhere, for all users.

Is there a global xmodmap file I can use? I'm running Debian.

Comment: It depends on the OS. For example in Fedora - /etc/X11/Xmodmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard system-wide xmodmap file. It depends on your distribution, on your display manager and on the user's desktop environment.

In Debian, I think all display managers run the global session startup scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` before they invoke the user's chosen session startup. So does `xinit`. As of jessie, this does not include any call to `xmodmap` (presumably because the default keyboard configuration is supposed to be done via XKB), but you can add your own script there.

You can put XKB settings in `xorg.conf`, but you can't reference an xmodmap file.